# How to get data using SELECT request

Tags: php, sql, symfony

I'm trying to display the statistics of carriers in my database. When I call the function but I get an error like:

```
class: "Doctrine\DBAL\Exception\SyntaxErrorException"
message: "An exception occurred while executing 'select count(cod_ser) TOTAL FROM public.tiers_datamart period =06-2019':↵↵SQLSTATE[42601]:
```

My code is this:

```
public function getTotalDatabyMonth($date, $type, $filtre) {
        $em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager('dbStat')->getConnection();
        if($filtre == null) {
            $restriction = "period =".$date;
        }else {
            $restriction = $type." = ".$filtre." AND period = ".$date;
        }
        $rawSql = "select count(".$type.") TOTAL FROM public.tiers_datamart ".$restriction;        
        $stmt = $em->prepare($rawSql);
        $stmt->execute();   
        $result = $stmt->fetchAll();    
        return intval($result[0]['total']);
    }

    public function getTotalDatabyMonths($dates, $type, $filtre) {
        $totalDatas = [];
        foreach($dates as $date){
            $total = $this->getTotalDatabyMonth($date, $type, $filtre);
            array_push($totalDatas, $total);
        }
        return $totalDatas;
    }
```

I call the function by `'data'=> $this->getTotalDatabyMonths($dataFormats[1], "cod_ser", $restriction)`

I tried to replace `$filtre` by `$restriction` in the method `getTotalDatabyMonths()` but it return the same value 12 times.

Comment: You need the word `WHERE` in that statement. `select count(cod_ser) TOTAL FROM public.tiers_datamart WHERE period =06-2019`

Comment: Or maybe `... WHERE period = "06-2019"` (quoted)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`$rawSql = "select count(".$type.") TOTAL FROM public.tiers_datamart WHERE ".$restriction;`

Add the WHERE and you are good to go.